# Android Muticolum listview onListItemClick

Tags: android

I have done Muticolum listview onListItemClick .Its working fine.Problem is

This line `String selection = l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();` return this 
`{routeName=TestRoute2, outlets=5, routeCode=VRT002}` .I want to get it selected row's 3rd column value.How to get it.

Please help me..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of Adapter? E.g. for a SimpleCursorAdapter you would do the following:

```
Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
long aLongValue = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("anintegercolumn"));
```

Comment: So you've feed a HashMap into the ListView? You will get HashMap<String, String> hashMap = (HashMap<String, String>) listView.getItemAtPosition(position); back then.

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> historyArrayList;
SimpleAdapter histroyListAdapter;

HashMap<String, String> historyObjectMap;

for (CheckInCheckOutHistory checkOutHistoryObj : checkInCheckOutHistoryList) {
    historyObjectMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        historyObjectMap.put("assetTag", checkOutHistoryObj.getAssetTag());
        historyObjectMap.put("action", checkOutHistoryObj.getAction());
     historyObjectMap.put("actionTime", checkOutHistoryObj.getActionDate());

        if (checkOutHistoryObj.getAction().equals("Checked out")) {
            historyObjectMap.put("gif", R.drawable.radio_button_yellow+ "");
        } else {
            historyObjectMap.put("gif", R.drawable.radio_button_green+ "");
        }

        historyArrayList.add(historyObjectMap);
}

histroyListAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            ViewCheckInCheckOutHistory.this, historyArrayList,
            R.layout.multi_colummn_list_text_style_small, new String[] {
                    "assetTag", "gif" , "action", "actionTime"},
                    new int[] { R.id.list_content_column1,
                            R.id.list_content_imagecolumn,
                            R.id.list_content_column3,
                            R.id.list_content_column4});

        historyListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                HashMap<String, String> historyObjectMapLocal = historyArrayList
                                    .get(position);
                final String assetTag = historyObjectMapLocal
                                    .get("assetTag");

                System.out.println("assetTag : " + assetTag);

            }
        });
```

In the above code the listView contents are populated using an ArrayList *historyArrayList*
and so the items at any column could be accessed using key ("assetTag", "gif" , "action", "actionTime").